# WYSIWYG - nesting elements

Tags: 2011

We're trying to implement a custom editor in CSS to allow the content editors to generate HTML in the following structure (in a Tridion 2011 SP1 environment)

```html
<div class="highlight">
    <h3>test</h3>
    <p>
        test paragraph
    </p>
    <p>
        test paragraph
    </p>
</div>
```

Adding the class `hightlight` to the `DIV` is no problem, but inserting other block elements like the `H3` and the `P`-tags, completely breaks the layout in the design view of the rich text field: `DIV` gets removed, the complete text become `H3`,... Inserting the plain HTML in the source works fine of course, but that's something we cannot ask the (non-technical) content editors.

- First question: Is this possible in the first place? (knowing the content editors only use Internet Explorer)
- If possible: should this be done using 'filtering XSLT', or specific editor configuration?
  -Modification of the stored HTML in the event system is the last option is possible, but the least favorite one.

Answer (score 3):

See your answers below:

- first question: is this possible in the first place (knowing the content editors only use Internet Explorer) - **Yes It is possible**
- if possible: should this be done using 'filtering XSLT', or specfic editor configuration - **The best recommendation from my side is "Filtering XSLT" option**
- modification of the stored HTML in the event system is the last option I see, but the least favorite one - **Least favorable option**

Another options could be:

- Manipulating TcmXHTML file - Not recommended but a possible solution with its own disadvantages
- Client Side manipulating - Not sure if suits your requirement

You may want to refer following questions for a better insight and might help you in the decision making:

[Disable-script-tags-within-rtf-fields](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/815/disable-script-tags-within-rtf-fields)

[How-can-you-preserve-empty-tags-in-an-rtf-field](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/698/how-can-you-preserve-empty-tags-in-an-rtf-field/714#714)